# Invalid XML file?

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I'm no good with XML files but I need to make a test using one and it looks like it's written incorrectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <command action="send" id="1234" [reconnect_after = 0] >
       <clip id="1">PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlb</clip>
       <clip id="2">kjshdf23987iewjfnb892q34qdhadhax</clip>
   </command>
</root>
```

I tested with an XML validator and these are the results:

```
Error:  Can not find declaration of element 'root'.
    Error Position: 
<root>

Error:  Element type "command" must be followed by attribute specifications: ">" or "/>".
    Error Position: 
<command action="resolve" id="1234" [reconnect_after = 0] >
```

Despite the error descriptions I really have no idea how to correct the file. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `[reconnect_after = 0]` with `reconnect_after="0"`.

Comment: works perfect now in my test program, despite the validator still says something about the root tag.

Comment: That warning is just because the validator doesn't have a DTD or Schema to check your XML follows the rules. It would like to know if a command is allowed to contain clip elements, for example.